# I am having trouble doing retopology for the hand, and I'm running into issues

Tags: modeling, edges, retopology

I am having trouble doing retopology for the hand. I have a few links/tutorials pulled up, but I can't seem to get it right.

[image]
As you can see here, I have 12 loops that make up the arm, and 8 loops that make up the fingers. I read that its best to go by 4's so that's what I did here.

[image]
In order to split it up, I was told originally to section off four faces for the thumb and use the remaining 8 faces to connect the hand to the starting joints of the fingers. Now, I know they look a bit wonky, but I was playing around with how I could successfully do this without running into a problem. I ran into a problem.. I have encountered another n-gon. The back of the index finger does not have a proper edge flow as it does in the front. I'm assuming it's because I did not account for something.

[image]

I am thinking it's because I did not account for the side of the pinky? Not sure. Here are some other ways I tried to fix the hand.
[image]
[image]

How it originally started out. I took the route of adding an edge loop around the thumb. I forgot why that didn't work either. I believe I had 8 loops wrapped around it.
Please forgive my long post. I have been up and at this for several days now. Let me know if a zip file is necessary for posting.